# Effective implementation of generic matching Tokens

Tags: parsing, scala, case-class, traits

This is a base trait that I use in my tiny parser app:

```
trait Token[ValueType] {
    def value: ValueType
}
```

This is what I require. I'd also like to combine a good feature of Java with a good feature of Scala i.e.:

- Java approach to enums (they're normal objects with methods, can ihnerit etc.)
- Scala suport for matching (readable code)

so an example of classes extending `Token` are:

```
// this to emulate Java enums; ProperEnumeration just adds some simple methods like fromChars etc.
object Keywords extends ProperEnumeration {
    val AND, ARRAY, BEGIN, CASE, CONST, ... = Value
}

// this to enable matching
final case class Keyword(keyword: Keywords.Value) extends Token[Keywords.Value] {
    def this(string: String) = this(Keywords.fromString(string))   
    def value = keyword
}

object SpecialSymbols extends ProperEnumeration {
    val LEFT_BRACE = Value("{")
    val RIGHT_BRACE = Value("}")
    ...
}

final case class SpecialSymbol(symbol: SpecialSymbols.Value) extends Token[SpecialSymbols.Value]     {
    def this(symbol: String) = this(SpecialSymbols.fromString(symbol))
    def value = symbol
}

// there are also non-enum subclasses of Token
case class Identifier(identifier: String) extends Token[String] {
    override def value: String = identifier
}
```

---

This is the best I came up with. I can use it like this:

```
token match {
    case Keyword(Keywords.BEGIN) => ...
    case SpecialSymbol(SpecialSymbols.LEFT_BRACE) => ...
    case Identifier(name) => ...
}
```

**I'd like to modify it to allow me to be more concise**, I'd like something like this:

```
token match {
        case Keyword.BEGIN => ... // or Keyword(BEGIN)
        case SpecialSymbol.LEFT_BRACE => ...
        case Identifier(name) => ...
    }
```

to also suport a method called `consume` that would work with any kind of `Token` subclass (`consume` should throw an exception if the next token from source is NOT the argument supplied).

```
consume(Keyword.BEGIN);
consume(SpecialSymbol.LEFT_BRACE);
consume(Identifier(name));
```

I want the code to be clean, that's why I use Scala in the first place. So I hope for no function overloads to allow easy addition of `Trait` subclasses.

So, dear Scalists, what to do?

Comment: Have you checked `Parser`-combinators in Scala?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to have

```
case Keyword(BEGIN) => ...
```

is to simply `import` the keywords:

```
import Keywords._
```

It won't require any other changes to your code.

Comment: hey, check this out http://pastebin.com/H0xRg4pj This is what I came up with. This is really nice, only that implicite defs dont seem to work under matching, i.e. `x match { case Keywords.BEGIN => .. }` doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

However, I personally would prefer to avoid `ProperEnumerarion` and have a simple hierarchy of traits and case objects:

```
trait Keyword
case object BEGIN extends Keyword
case object CASE extends Keyword
```

This will automatically give pattern matching:

```
token match {
  case BEGIN => ...
}
```

If you need some methods in objects you may have them declared in the trait of have some abstract class (with a constructor):

```
abstract class Keyword(val name:String) {
  def myMethod = "Keyword."+name
}
case object BEGIN extends Keyword("BEGIN")
case object CASE extends Keyword("CASE")
```

**UPD:** You may use an object that instantiates "enum" instances the same way as Enumeration:

```
object AllMyKeywords {
  val BEGIN = Keyword("BEGIN")
  val CASE = Keyword("CASE")
  // etc.
  val values = List(BEGIN, CASE, ...).map(k => (k.name, k)).toMap
}
```

**UPD2:** There is also a way to make pattern matching with strings:

```
abstract class Keyword(val name:String) {
  def unapply(str:String):Option[Keyword] = {
    if(AllMyKeywords.values.contains(str))
      Some(AllMyKeywords.values(str)
    else
      None
  }
}
```

In this case the `unapply` method is implemented by every `BEGIN`, `CASE` keywords and thus it is directly called (at least I think so).

```
"BEGIN" match { case BEGIN => ??? }
```

Comment: this trait would require me to repeat `case class X extends Keyword` like 100 Times... this is why I use enum, to JUST enumerate the options w/o any clutter